# How to Preload product pictures in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, preload, image-preloader

Can you please help me on how to preload product pics in Shopify?

My load delay time is too long due to photos not being loaded sooner. I've tried a lot of codes suggested in Google but it didnt seem to work. I've attached a screenshot from developer tools that show the load delay time.

The code I tried:

{{ product.featured_image | image_url: width: 600 | image_tag: preload: true }}

as suggested on here => shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/theme-check/checks/asset-preload

I used the code in theme.liquid below head tag.

Comment: Can you use a CDN to middleware the files for you, would increase load times around the world as well?  Also, welcome to Stack Overflow, when you say "I've tried code", we like to see that code so it can be reviwed for modfication.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I've tried this,

{{ product.featured_image | image_url: width: 600 | image_tag: preload: true }}

as suggested on here => https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/theme-check/checks/asset-preload

I used the code in theme.liquid below <head> tag.

Comment: How big is the image file, what file format as it in, and have you tried cropping the image to the 600 width and then uploading it so that the file is smaller and thus loads faster?  And what makes you sure that the preload is not working?

Comment: The image is .jpg and 45kb, other pics are also about the same in terms of size.

I dont think the page is slow, but you know the lighthouse. It's obvious that pics load later than the other elements like h1, description etc. But, it's miliseconds. The screenshot is for mobile also, desktop result is way better.

In order to fix load delay, I need to preload the images but I couldn't do it. I dont know if there is any other way, tbh.